# node.js PDFTron HTML to PDF conversion failed

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, pdftron

I am trying to convert html to PDF file using PDFTron

```js
const { PDFNet } = require('@pdftron/pdfnet-node');

async function main() {
    // Start with a PDFDoc (the conversion destination)
    const doc = await PDFNet.PDFDoc.create();
    const converter = await PDFNet.HTML2PDF.create();

    // add from HTML String data
    converter.insertFromHtmlString(htmlSource);

    // add from a web page location
    //converter.insertFromUrl(webPageLocation);

    // apply conversion
    const page = await converter.convert(doc);

     //doc.pagePushBack(page);
     doc.save('aaa.pdf',PDFNet.SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_linearized); }
  PDFNet.runWithCleanup(main,licenseKey).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  }).then(function(){ PDFNet.shutdown(); });
```

,
and get the following error:
[image]

On the download site:
"
https://www.pdftron.com/download-center/windows/?language=All#modules-html2pdf-conversion-module%5Cn
"

I found no mention of html2PDF.

Does anyone know the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the HTML2PDF module here: https://www.pdftron.com/download-center/windows/?language=All#modules_html2pdf-conversion-module

And then use `HTML2PDF.SetModulePath` and pass in the path to the folder where you extracted `HTML2PDF` into.

See sample:
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/node/js/HTML2PDFTest/

Comment: I installed the HTML2PDF library and used 'getModulePath', and it works!!!
Thank you!!